# cronjob to play files in a folder with ffmpeg causes delay between songs. how to avoid?

Tags: linux, loops, ffmpeg, cron

I have a cron set up to check for a specific stream and if its not playing(usually means that file is over) it will randomly select other file.

The command:
/root/bin/ffmpeg -re -i $(ls /usr/btv/btvconcerts/*.mp4 | shuf -n 1) -vcodec copy -preset superfast -acodec copy -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv OUTPUT

The problem I have is that the cron is running every 1 minute and so there could be a delay between the streaming files for up to 1 min + the time it launches etc

Is there a command i could use just to constantly loop through the files without crontab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sh/bash/dash/ash/zsh/etc.:

```
while true
do
   ...
done
```

Comment: while true
do
/root/bin/ffmpeg -re -i $(ls /usr/btv/btvconcerts/*.mp4 | shuf -n 1) -vcodec copy -preset superfast -acodec copy -ar 44100 -ab 32k -f flv OUTPUT
done - like that?

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, but with command separators (such as semicolons or newlines) instead of as one long line.

Comment: Ignacio: can you please suggest how to use command separators in this case? I never had to use them before.